# macports build error

Tags: macos, imagemagick, macports

Anyone seen this before?

```
version:1
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (p7zip)
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (p7zip)
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (p7zip)
:debug:main setting option extract.cmd to /usr/bin/bzip2
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.extract (p7zip)
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.patch (p7zip)
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.configure (p7zip)
:msg:main --->  Building p7zip
:debug:build build phase started at Sun Jul 24 17:36:04 MST 2011
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (p7zip)
:debug:build Environment: CPATH='/opt/local/include' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_archivers_p7zip/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS' LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib' CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.7'
:debug:build Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_archivers_p7zip/work/p7zip_9.20.1" && /usr/bin/make -j4 all3'
:info:build sh: line 0: cd: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_archivers_p7zip/work/p7zip_9.20.1: No such file or directory
:info:build shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_archivers_p7zip/work/p7zip_9.20.1" && /usr/bin/make -j4 all3 " returned error 1
:error:build Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:build Backtrace: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for p7zip): org.macports.destroot org.macports.build
:notice:build Log for p7zip is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_archivers_p7zip/main.log
```

I got this error in the log when trying to run:

```
$sudo port install ImageMagick
--->  Building p7zip
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
Log for p7zip is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_archivers_p7zip/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error: Unable to execute port: upgrade p7zip failed
To report a bug, see <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
-MacBook-Pro:picasso xxxx$ /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_archivers_p7zip/main.log
-bash: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_archivers_p7zip/main.log: Permission denied
```

Comment: What is in the log for p7zip - this tells what the error is - the top log just syas there was an error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the **Upgrade of p7zip** did not succeed. 
Try `sudo port uninstall p7zip` and `sudo port clean --all vile` get rid of 'possible' corrupted fetched ports, then `sudo port install p7zip`.

When all this is done, try again `sudo port install ImageMagick`.